# Кнопки изменения рейтинга на ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Нужно реализовать ajax-запросы голосования "за" и "против" к комментариям, по аналогии как на Баше: т.е. при нажатии на кнопку не происходит перезагрузка страницы, а только меняется рейтинг. И как это событие обработать в джанговском представлении? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем сделал так: навесил на кнопки функцию:

```
function voite(id, action){
    $.post("/quote/", {comment_id: id, comment_action: action});
}
```

А на адрес '/quote/' навесил обработчик во вьюхе, обрабатывающий пост-запрос.
Если нужно(интересно) - могу привести более детальный код.

**Дополнение.**

Скажу заранее, что обработчик лежит в отдельном приложении и обрабатывает страницу '/quote/', т.е. в urls.py есть такая строчка:

(r'^quote/$', 'ajax.views.quote'), где 'ajax.views.quote' - путь к обработчику. Вот сам текст обработчика:

```
def quote(request):

    message = "This is a technic page"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'comment_id' in request.POST and 'comment_action' in request.POST:
            #обрабатываем запрос, повышаем/понижаем рейтинг и т.д.

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

В обработчике проверяем метод, далее извлекаем из запроса (request) параметры и делай все что нам нужно.

Comment: Нужно и интересно. Если кода немного, приведите самую суть.

Comment: @ХэшКод Примите мой ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Обощаю модераторов, делают именно так, как нужно :) Таких бы везде...

Comment: @metazet Нужно выделить вставляемый код и нажать на кнопку 101010, тогда будут правильные отступы. Или, как вариант, уже в исходном редакторе добавить табуляцию перед вставкой кода. Markdown трактует как код текст, в начале которого есть отступ в 4 пробела или в одну табуляцию.

Comment: Вроде как, get быстрее чем post

Comment: У меня обрабатываемая информация простая, поэтому разница минимальна. Да и я параноик, не хочу что бы открыто мелькали id-шники ;)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [django-voting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/).

Comment: Попробую django-voting, потом отпишусь здесь о результатах. Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score -1):

Для реализации данного функционала, я бы посоветовал Вам использовать шаблоны. В шаблоне вы задаете класс и/или id элемента, создаете кнопку, обработчик которой, находящийся в JavsScript-коде, меняет состояние нужного элемента по его классу или id. Если страница не требует общения с сервером, можно и вовсе не отправлять запрос. На сколько мне известно в Django имеется многоуровневая промежуточная обработка запросов, которая позволяет обрабатывать запрос различных стадиях.

Comment: Так мне и нужны эти обработчики(пример), хотя бы джанговский... 

Comment: @metazet Для комментариев лучше использовать комментарии.